# Vectorisation calculation using 2 arrays of the same column in pandas/numpy python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a vector calculation such that it takes in a value from an array and the value below that array. It checks to see if the above value is 1 and the below value is 0. If this is the case, using np.where I will assign 1 for true and 0 for false. The error I am seeming to get is: 'could not broadcast input array from shape (6,) into shape (5,)'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {
    'A': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    'B': [0,0,0,0,0,0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
x=1
df.iloc[0:5,1]=np.where((df.iloc[0:5,0]==1) & (df.iloc[1:6,0]==0),x,0)
```

Each `df.iloc` is of the same size and the last row is just a dummy row to allow `df.iloc[1:6,0]` to work.

Also when running the boolean I get:

```
(df.iloc[0:5,0]==1) & (df.iloc[1:6,0]==0)
Out[43]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
```

But value 2 should be true. I've also tried making x an array but it doesn't seem to work, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: "*the above value is 1 and the below value is 0*" the row matching this description is the index 3, can you provide the exact expected output?

Comment: Posting as a comment because time limitation: The `&` operation works index-wise, so you end up getting a series of size equal to 6. To fix this, simply work with boolean array values rather than `pandas Series`:

    `df.iloc[0:20,1]=np.where((df.iloc[0:5,0]==1).values & (df.iloc[1:6,0]==0).values,x,0)`

Comment: Your explanation is unclear. However, in general this kind of problem can be solved with `shift` function in Pandas.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Answer (score 0):

The exact logic is unclear, but you need to use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
# the current value is 1 and the below value is 0
m = df['A'].eq(1) & df['A'].shift(-1).eq(0)
df['out'] = np.where(m, 1, 0)

# the above value is 1 and the below value is 0
m2 = df['A'].shift().eq(1) & df['A'].shift(-1).eq(0)
df['out2'] = np.where(m2, 1, 0)
```

If you want to map `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`, no need for `np.where`, just use `m.astype(int)`.

Output:

```
   A  B  out  out2
0  0  0    0     0
1  0  0    0     0
2  1  0    1     0
3  0  0    0     1
4  0  0    0     0
5  0  0    0     0
```